# How can I subtract two dates and exclude if dates in between are a Tuesday or a Holiday?

Tags: sql, toad, toad-data-point

I have a table with two dates and another table that identifies the day of the week and if that day is a federal holiday. I am going to subtract the two dates from table 1 but I need to be sure that if any day between those two days is identified as a Tuesday from the second table or if it's a holiday, to exclude that from my results. Example, 9/29/2023 & 10/3/2023 should give me a total of 2 days, not 3.

I was thinking a case when statement would work but as I wrote it I realized I needed to check what happened in between the dates so that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Problems like this are easily solved by joining to a Calendar table.

Comment: Which database do you use? TOAD - originally - stands for "Tools for **Oracle** Application Development", but Quest offers TOAD also for MySQL, MS SQL Server, DB2, possibly PostgreSQL. Date arithmetic operations differ, and so does solution. Therefore, which database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE,'9/29/2023',101)
DECLARE @SecondDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE,'10/3/2023',101)

PRINT (DATEDIFF(DD, @FirstDate, @SecondDate)) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @FirstDate,  GETDATE()) * 2) -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @FirstDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This is product-specific SQL - but the OP has not provided any info on which vendor/platform they are using.